# The meaning of そうなる in this context

Tags: meaning

Does そうなる have a meaning besides "become so" when used in this sorta context?

> Speaker A:あなた、それに興味ある？
>   Speaker B: うん...まあ、そうなるかな

It looks to me like it doesn't mean "become so", but something more like "I wonder if it's so". Is that wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That なる is difficult.

The original sentence, そうなるかな, is equivalent to (これは)そういうことになるかな。, (これは)そういう話になるかな。 or (これは)興味あることになるかな。.

なる has a meaning like evaluation. For example, 盗まれた紙幣は30億円になる。 does not mean "The stolen bills become 3 billion yen." but "The stolen bills are evaluated as 3 billion yen."

The direct translation should be like "This whole situation may indicate (or be evaluated as a story) that I am interested in it."

Comment: Just to throw in what it a non-direct translation would be (since there isn't one in the answer): "You could say so" or "I guess so."